# Не выполнять обновления ОС пока работают определённые приложения

Tags: windows, ос

Есть ли в Win10 какие нибудь средства для того чтобы указать какие приложения являются критически важными, и во время работы которых нельзя выполнять обновление ОС, не смотря на то что оператор отошёл от ПК?

Суть проблемы - винда скачивает обнову, далее ждёт пока я сам выполню обновление. Но, есть сценарий, который определяет что если за ПК никто не сидит довольно продолжительное время (около часа или двух), обновление может начать устанавливаться самостоятельно.

Во время работы я могу оставлять сборки или тесты, винду не заботят ни работающая Visual Studio, ни работающая IDEA, ни какие либо другие приложения, на вроде скачивающего файлы торрента. В итоге принудительная перезагрузка ради установки обновлений просто бьёт файлы, сводит на нет часовые тесты или сборки. Гит делает перерасчёт кеша, или пытается пушить по сценарию в репу? Винду так же не интересует, ломаются ветки и кеши.

Это уже не просто раздражает, не знаю куда деваться с этими обновлениями, отключать их бесполезно, они всё равно в какой то момент приходят, и снова винда перезагрузится наплевав на то что идёт работа. Если бы можно было пометить приложения так, чтобы ОС понимала что щас идёт критически важная работа, и не смотря на то что нет оператора выполнять перезагрузку просто нельзя - было бы идеально. Если так нельзя, есть ли другие способы избежать проблем?

Comment: Можно в настройках изменить период активности, если примерно известно время, в которое нельзя перезагружаться

Comment: @Стас, Спасибо, увеличил этот период, надеюсь есть ещё что нибудь

Comment: лайфхак - ставим мышку на кулер \ вентилятор и гуляем скок влезет. если под рукой нет кулера, можно запустить какой нибудь макрос(создает ивенты клавы и мыши, тем самым эмитируя бурную деятельность пользователя). а вообще, кажется вам надо заглянуть в "планировщик заданий".